# How is \documentclass an "Undefined control sequence"?

Tags: auctex, input-encodings

I'm using AUCTeX 11.90 on emacs (recently upgraded from elpa packages) running on Windows 7. I've created a tex file and for some reason only this one particular file gives error msgs when I compile it with pdflatex (`C-c C-c`): "Undefined control sequence" pointing at `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` How is this even possible?

I suspected some encoding conflict so I started the 1st line of the document (which btw is the result of an org file export) with: `% -*- coding: utf-8; -*-`

The problem nevertheless persisted. The bottom part of emacs' buffer now looks like this:

[image: U in left-most corner of buffer]

---

### EDIT 1

Here are the first few lines from the file's log (`ccna1-ch10.log`):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdftex 2015.6.28)  23 MAY 2017 21:49
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input ./ccna1-ch10.tex
(./ccna1-ch10.tex
./ccna1-ch10.tex:2: Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \documentclass
                  [10pt]{article}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Does this make sense? It stops right at the beginning, won't even go beyond `\documentclass[...]{article}`. May it have something to do with the .emacs file?

Comment: This seems like you're compiling with TeX, not LaTeX...?

Comment: Your screenshot says that Emacs saves the buffer in UTF8 with Windows line ending (CR/LF).  Your file should compile fine with LaTeX with this line in your preamble `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.  I also suspect AUCTeX is running TeX and not LaTeX on your file.

Comment: `preloaded format=pdftex` -> you're running `pdftex` rather than `pdflatex`, I think.

Comment: Ok, so why are all other .tex files in the same folder, compiling without problems? They too are are run by pdftex but there are no problems.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this problem, as Werner told you in his comment, is, that you are running `TeX` instead of `LaTeX`. You can advise `emacs` to automatically run `LaTeX`. To do so, you should have a look at the *local variable* comments of the file. They should look, e.g., like:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

The first and the list line are only magic markers. The second line tells `emacs` to use the `latex` mode. The third line tells AucTeX, that the file itself is the main file of the document.

If your file does not have such a section, add it. If the `mode` line differs, change it.Then save the file and press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (in `emacs` syntax `C-c` `C-n`) or close it and load it again.

After this, `C-c` `C-c` should run LaTeX instead of (plain)TeX.

If this does not help, you can set the mode manually using `M-x latex-mode`.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't quite work. I'm still getting an error msg only this time it says: " LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.

--- TeX said ---
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual." and an `amsmath.sty` file opens up in a buffer. Yet, I don't have any math in my tex file.

Comment: @WobblyWindows I've told you how to make AucTeX run LaTeX instead of (plain)TeX. An already defines `\iint` would be another problem and therefore another question. And we would need a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to find the reason and a solution.